# Return the first iteration of a sequence from a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, math, functional-programming

I have an array of sequences, with infinite iterations (e.g. [6,6,6,6,6] or [23, 24, 23, 24] or [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4])
How do I iterate through each such list in Haskell and return only the first iteration? In case of the above examples: [6]; [23, 24]; [1, 2, 3, 4]

Thanks!

Edit: Sorry, I wasn't precise. The lists are indeed infinte. My goal is to return a list of the aliquot sequence of a given Integer. I have a function which returns the sum of the dividers. I started a recursive call with the first sum, and constructed the list. That resulted in lists like [6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6...].

First I wanted to solve the problem by taking the first part of the list, up to the second occurrence of the original Int. But then it hit me: It's easier to check with `elem` if the sum exists in the list. If yes, return the list as-is. Otherwise, append the sum and go on.

Edit 2: The code that produces the (in my definition at least) infinite list is the following chunk:

```
aliquot :: (Integral a) => a -> [a]
aliquot 0 = []
aliquot 1 = [1]
aliquot n = n : (aliquot $ sum $ divisors n)

divisors :: (Integral a) => a -> [a]
divisors n = filter ((0 ==) . (n `mod`)) [1 .. (n `div` 2)]
```

Comment: @WillNess I don't think the problem says what you think it says.

Comment: Is this a homework? If yes, can you quote the assignment verbatim?

Comment: There are more problems here than you can shake a stick at. An aliquot sequence cannot continue past 1 since the sum of proper divisors of 1 is 0. Sum of proper divisors of `23` is `1`. Sum of proper divisors of `24` is `36`. An aliquot sequence is not necessarily periodic but might have an initial subsequence that does not repeat (95,25,6,6,6...).

Comment: I know, this is just a starting place I found online. I could solve those problems - the problem I asked here is plain and simple. I solved it by not running into the problem in the first place.

Comment: I updated the code in the Q.

Comment: Wow. This needs to become the new textbook example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386992). Your "x" is the easy problem "how do I generate an aliquot sequence", and your "y" is the literally impossible "how do I find the period of an infinite list".

Comment: Thanks for the link. Wow indeed. It would be however easy to solve if I were to look for the first occurence of the original Integer, or am I missing something?

Comment: It is not known whether all aliquot sequences are periodic. Some of them might be infinite and unbounded. If your assignment says "return the aliquot sequence", then you *probably* should return an infinite sequence without trying to cut off the repeating part. If it says something else, you might just as well tell us what it actually says. It's included in the price.

Comment: @n.m. I've made an edit so the point becomes clear which I think you had in mind.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible. Consider this sequence: `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1...` It looks like the answer here is `[1]`, right? Wrong. That sequence was actually the greatest common factor of (x^17 + 9) and ((x + 1)^17 + 9), which stops being all 1s once you get to the 8424432925592889329288197322308900672459420460792433rd element. Or consider this other sequence: `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1...`. The world's greatest mathematicians aren't sure what the answer is for this sequence. It's the smallest number ever reached by the Collatz sequence for each starting value, and although we've never found a number where this isn't 1, we haven't been able to actually prove that it will be 1 for all numbers.

Comment: This is all fine and dandy, but all sequences in the question are finite, so let's just consider those.

Comment: @n.m. From the question: "with infinite iterations"

Comment: I tend to trust code more than words. `[6,6,6,6,6]` is obviously finite.

Comment: It might be stipulated in the assignment that as soon as one of the previously seen elements is seen again, we may assume the cycle has been detected. i.e. this might be a constraint on the input numbers.

Comment: Or it might be that OP isn't using the word "infinite" properly. Perhaps the correct word is "unlimited". I have no idea, maybe OP could chime in and answer the question I have asked in the comments. It's a rather futile effort otherwise. The question as it stands conflates two very different problems, one trivial (how to map through a list) and one less so (how to extract a period from a (finite?) periodic sequence). Such problems don't tend to occur as assignments in introductory courses. Perhaps OP mistranscribed it for SO.

Comment: It is indeed an infinite list. If you call the function in hugs, you can whatch the console printing [6,6,6,...] forever. Isn‘t that the definition of infinite? If I pass the list into anothjer function, it results in SO

Comment: @schoeberlt hugs is obsolete for the last 10 years or so.

Comment: We can use ghci or whatever interpreter we want. But they require the code to run under hugs on a linux machine on campus